# cant download zip file from php function

Tags: php

am calling this function to create and download zip. the create is working but my screen freezes when the system is about to download it, then shows a bunch of abstract writings without download

```
function zipF(){
$track = $_POST['track'];
$cartid = $_POST['cartid'];

$zip = new ZipArchive;
    if ($zip->open('myzip.zip',  ZipArchive::CREATE)) {
        $notan = DataDB::getInstance()->select_from_where('order_image','cartid',$cartid);  
        foreach($notan as $row){
        $zip->addFile('../img/tempfil/'.$row['image'], $row['image']);
        }
        $zip->close();
        $archive_file_name ="myzip.zip";
       header("Content-type: application/zip"); 
       header("Content-Disposition: attachment; 
       filename=$archive_file_name");
       header("Content-length: " . filesize($archive_file_name));
       header("Pragma: no-cache"); 
       header("Expires: 0"); 
       readfile("$archive_file_name");
      echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">
                            <strong>Error!</strong> Problem with your order details.'.$track.'
            </div>';
       } else {
         echo 'Failed!';
       }
 }
```

Comment: Try just serving a precreated zip file on your server already to rule out any issues with creating one etc.  Why are you echoing after the read file?  You need to exit or that content will become part of the file.  Beware of scope within a function...not sure what it considers getcwd() but it might not have the zip file in it.

Comment: still not working, still freezing